# Using Model property inside <p> along side with text in mvc3 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to make this

```
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddressVN) </br>
   Tel: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tel) / Fax: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Fax) </br>
   Email: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email) </p>
```

But the parser throw exception. How to place my model property along side with pure text?

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh! Slight issue with your HTML is causing Razor to panic.

Note the following:

```
</br>
```

It's **back to front**! You're trying to **close** a tag `br`, but as you're mid-Razor, it's Razor that's throwing the error.

Simply change it to:

```
<br/>
```

And all will work :)

Comment: Work as expected. Thanks very much, Sir!!